# Using pgfplots, why do I get "undefined control sequence" when trying to use a foreach variable as a parameter to addplot?

Tags: pgfplots

Since I have multiple plots with error bars, I would like to shift the error bars slightly to make the overall plot more readable. However, when I try to do this using the variable of a `\foreach` as the amount to shift, I get an "undefined control sequence" error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\foreach \x/\y in {a/-1cm, b/0cm, c/1cm} {
    \addplot+ [
        %every error bar/.append style={xshift=\y},
        %every node/.style={xshift=\y},
        error bars/y dir=both,
        error bars/y explicit,
    ] coordinates {
        (0, 0) +- (0, 1)
        (1, 0) +- (0, 1)
        (2, 0) +- (0, 1)
    };
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(The document does not compile when I uncomment either one of the two comments.)

What's wrong here?

**EDIT**: Added another variable to the `\foreach`. In my actual use-case it would contain the filename to plot data from or the label to use for the curve.

Comment: Use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` instead of `\foreach`

Comment: @percusse: I think in this case it's even necessary to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`, otherwise all the bars are moved by the distance specified last in the list.

Comment: @Vegard: I assume with the `every node` style you're trying to move the plot markers? In that case, you'll have to use `every mark/.style`.

Comment: @Jake Now that I've tested it, I think `every error bar` is not the way to go for such use. ... Oops didn't see your comment.

Comment: @percusse/@Jake: AFAICS, `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`/`\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` don't support multiple variables :-( (In my use-case I plot data from different files in each iteration of the loop). Also, why do you guys add comments instead of answers?

Comment: We are just too shy :) As you can see, it's better to be sure about the answer before posting. Can you provide a minimal use case where you have different variables such that we are sure that we are answering a question that you ask rather than what we think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is a macro expansion issue: the `\y` variable is evaluated later - but at that "later" time, the loop has been finished and `\y` is undefined.

As already mentioned, `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` has just one loop argument (note that `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` supports two arguments, but it does not help here).

Here is one approach which does *always* work, no matter how complicated your loops are:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\foreach \x/\y in {a/-1cm, b/0cm, c/1cm} {
    \edef\temp{
        \noexpand\addplot+ [
            every error bar/.append style={xshift=\y},
            every node/.style={xshift=\y},
            error bars/y dir=both,
            error bars/y explicit,
        ]
        coordinates {
        (0, 0) +- (0, 1)
        (1, 0) +- (0, 1)
        (2, 0) +- (0, 1)
        };
    }
    \temp
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I introduced an artifical `\edef` which covers the complete loop body. This `\edef` means "expanded definition": it defines `\temp` to be the fully expanded result of everything inside of the curly braces. This will expand `\y` to the current loop value. Unfortunately, it will also (try to) expand `\addplot` - which is impossible. To avoid this expansion, I wrote the TeX primitive `\noexpand` in front of `\addplot`.

Finally, `\temp` contains the loop body *without* any references to `\y` or `\x`. We can simply execute it by writing `\temp` into the loop body. That does the job.

---

Just for the curious: you could leave the coordinate list outside of the `\edef`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\foreach \x/\y in {a/-1cm, b/0cm, c/1cm} {
    \edef\temp{
        \noexpand\addplot+ [
            every error bar/.append style={xshift=\y},
            every node/.style={xshift=\y},
            error bars/y dir=both,
            error bars/y explicit,
        ]
    }
    \temp
        coordinates {
        (0, 0) +- (0, 1)
        (1, 0) +- (0, 1)
        (2, 0) +- (0, 1)
    };
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

this does also work because TeX works by means of expansion - as soon as it "executes" `\temp`, it does no longer know anything about the fact that it is "inside" of `\temp` and will simply read ahead.

See http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf for details