# Foreach and different color compilation error

Tags: color, foreach

if you execute this code there will be a compilation error, but if you replace `red!\rnb!blue` by `red!20!blue` it works fine.

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \def\K{1}

    \begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, axis y line = left ,
    width=13cm, height=\axisdefaultheight,
    ymax=1.85*\K,axis lines=none,
    ytick=\empty,extra y ticks={\K}, extra y tick labels={},extra y tick style={grid=major},
    xtick=\empty,
    ]
    \foreach \z/\rnb in {0.1/10,0.2/20}{
        %\def\z{0.1}
        \def\T{1}
        \def\w{3.14159*2}
        \addplot[samples=2,domain=0:5.2*\T,thick=1pt] { \K };
        \addplot[red!\rnb!blue,samples=20,domain=0:1*\T,thick=3pt,ultra thick] {  
        ( 1 - ( (exp(-\w*\z*\x)/sqrt(1-\z^2)) *cos((\w*\x*sqrt(1-\z^2) - (atan(\z/sqrt(1-\z^2))*3.14159/180) ) *180/3.14159) )  ) *\K};
    }

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \end{document}
```

Why is that?

Comment: I think this is a general problem whenever you want to do a foreach loop inside the axis env. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/3929, I've used that `\temp` trick a few times, seems to work just fine.

Comment: @daleif You are right, but here there is a minor extra point. I will be happy to delete my answer if this extra point does not make a difference. (However, if this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/3929, then IMHO https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/3929 should be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71199/121799.)

Comment: @marmot you know tikz/pgf much better than I do, I just googled pgfplots and foreach

Comment: @daleif No, you gave a perfectly valid link which solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not decided whether this is a duplicate of e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69445/121799). Here there is slight additional complication that you need to replace `\x` by `x` in the arguments of the plots, otherwise everything that has been said [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71199/121799) applies.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\K{1}

\begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, axis y line = left ,
width=13cm, height=\axisdefaultheight,
ymax=1.85*\K,axis lines=none,
ytick=\empty,extra y ticks={\K}, extra y tick labels={},extra y tick style={grid=major},
xtick=\empty,
]
\foreach \z/\rnb in {0.1/10,0.2/20}{
    %\def\z{0.1}
    \def\T{1}
    \def\w{3.14159*2}
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[samples=2,domain=0:5.2*\T,thick=1pt] { \K };
    \noexpand\addplot[red!\rnb!blue,samples=20,domain=0:1*\T,thick=3pt,ultra thick] {  
    ( 1 - ( (exp(-\w*\z*x)/sqrt(1-\z^2)) *cos((\w*x*sqrt(1-\z^2) - (atan(\z/sqrt(1-\z^2))*3.14159/180) ) *180/3.14159) )  ) *\K};}
    \temp
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll have a look at the other answer, I hadn't seen it before.

Comment: Other techniques that appear to work: 1) `\global\let\mytmprnb\rnb (...)  \addplot[red!\mytmprnb!blue, (...)`, 2) `\def\tmp{\addplot[red!} \expandafter\tmp\rnb !blue, (...)` and 3) `\newcommand*{\myaddplot}[1]{\addplot[red!#1!blue, (...) *\K};} \begin{axis}(...) \addplot[samples=2,domain=0:5.2*\T,thick=1pt] { \K }; \expandafter\myaddplot\expandafter{\rnb} } \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @frougon Yes, thanks! However, conceptually it is more or less the same, isn't it? You need to make sure that the loop variables are expanded when `\addplot` "sees" them. There are also specific loop commands for that, most notably `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`, but without extra tricks this one takes only one variable.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely not claiming my solutions are better. In fact, I was a bit surprised to see that `\foreach` didn't expand the `\rnb` while unrolling the loop, so just played around a bit. :-) daleif's [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/3929) seems to give an explanation, though. (that's what I wrote “appear to work”: I was not 100% sure why some work and others don't)

Comment: @frougon It is not only the `\foreach` but also the survey phase of `pgfplots` as far as I understand things. If you use `\foreach` with ordinary Ti*k*Z paths, these issues do not arise in this form. What I want to say is that `\addplot` gets used twice.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's the `\foreach` that causes problems (you know  it better than I!) but apparently, `\addplot` stores the tokens in its optional argument without expanding them at first. And when it does, it's too late. That's how I understand the problem and why our workarounds work, at least.

Comment: @frougon Yes, this is what I think is true.

Comment: I have to correct myself: despite the 3 methods I gave [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499640/foreach-and-different-color-compilation-error/499644?noredirect=1#comment1261960_499644) compile, only number 2 and 3 actually work as designed. Number 1 doesn't work correctly: `\addplot` will only use the last color blend for each curve, because what it stores is the control sequence token `\mytmprnb`, as opposed to the *value* `\rnb` has in each loop iteration. Because of the `\global\let`, the control sequence is defined when used, hence no error, but all curves use the same value.