# PGFplots - `\addplot` and `\foreach` won't compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I am trying to use some of the TikZ and PGFMath tools (e.g. `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` and `\foreach`) to make plotting things easier. However, I can't get the following code to compile. There seems to be a bad interaction between the `\addplot` command and the `\foreach` command. It compiles fine when either of those is commented out, but not when they are both present.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{0.3+0.3*#1-1*#1^2+0.65*#1^3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot{{f(x)}} node(endofplot)[anchor=west]{$f$};
    \foreach \n in {8,12,16}
        \node [above] at (\n,0) {$\n$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/3929, you need to use a different type of foreach

Comment: also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71199/79060, an answer posted by author of `pgfplots`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved - the commands inside `\foreach` need to wrapped in `\edef\temp{\noexpand` and `}\temp` tags. I'll make this answer community wiki, so someone with actual TeX knowledge can explain why this works.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{0.3+0.3*#1-1*#1^2+0.65*#1^3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot{{f(x)}} node(endofplot)[anchor=west]{$f$};
    \foreach \n in {8,12,16}
        \edef\temp{\noexpand
           \node [above] at (\n,0) {$\n$};
        }\temp
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Per @muzimuzhi's comment, this answer by Christian Feuersänger explains why this works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69445/using-pgfplots-why-do-i-get-undefined-control-sequence-when-trying-to-use-a-f/71199#71199